# Low Battery Crash with no Battery Usage on ipad 2 with ios 8.3

Tags: ipad, battery, crash

My iPad 2 has been crashing recently with no warning and then takes several hours charging before it comes back to life. When it crashes there is only a low battery icon, and no charging symbol when it is plugged in. When it comes back it shows 100% until it crashes.

The Low Battery charge crash log shows

- Hardware Model: K93AP
- Awake Time: 10:48:43 (38922)
- Standby Time: 62:01:16 (223276)
- Partial Charge: 0
- Capacity: 100
- Voltage: 3709 mV

I have reinstalled iOS 8.3 from scratch to no avail. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: The battery may be damaged and need replacement. Is it under warranty or AppleCare+ or insurance? If so, have it brought to the appropriate place to inspect and possibly replace it. If not, it may be worth buying a battery replacement kit and trying it yourself. But that repair is apparently very difficult.

Comment: Forgot the link to instructions and parts. https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPad+2+Wi-Fi+EMC+2560+Battery+Replacement/13706

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The iPad is too old for warranty and I don't want to melt it apart. An Apple store checked the battery and said it was OK, it seems to be more of a reporting problem as the battery works, it is just reported as 100% or it crashes.